# didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler not being called when app is in background and inactive

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In the application active state, the didReceiveRemoteNotification method is called and when the application is in the background and inactive state the didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not called.

Code:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){
  
    NSLog("Push Received: \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Comment: what is the reason you are expecting `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to be called in background?

Answer (score 1):

If you want below method to call

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

in background mode using remote notification. you need to send **content-available : 1** in aps payload as silent notification then only it will awake your app from background mode. And if you want you can configure local alert notification using same payload.

Answer (score 0):

If it calms you down, I had the same problem and I did nothing to fix this, because after a few hours my application started to receive notification in the background. But if it doesn't help, you should try sending notifications manually using ARC, and check notification status.